# Исправление предложения с деепричастным оборотом

Tags: грамотная-речь, синтаксис, типы-ошибок

*Глядя на то, что происходит, у меня опускаются руки.*
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно исправить предложение с нарушенным деепричастным оборотом?

Answer (score 3):

*Глядя на то, что происходит, у меня опускаются руки.*
Никаких ошибок в самом деепричастном обороте ("глядя на то, что происходит") нет.

Разбираем предложение: руки опускаются (основное действие) и глядят (добавочное).
Имеется **синтаксическая ошибка** в предложении с обособленным обстоятельством, выраженным деепричастным оборотом (классический пример: *Отдыхая в кресле, передо мной висит картина «Март»*).

Возможная правка (с сохранением деепричастного оборота):
**Глядя на то, что происходит, я опускаю руки.**

[Деепричастный оборот: как не ошибиться](https://sudarevaru.wordpress.com/2018/07/13/%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82/)
[Опустить руки](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8) — стать бездеятельным вследствие отсутствия энергии, надежды.

Answer (score 2):

Прежде всего надо бы исправить заголовок. В предложении, вероятно, нарушена **грамматика**, то есть правила использования деепричастного оборота. А не сам оборот.

По сути же вопроса могу предложить
***Когда я гляжу на то, что происходит, у меня опускаются руки.***

Вообще переделка в придаточное - это универсальный прием исправления подобных ошибок. Важно только не переусердствовать - и не потерять при такой правке смысл, подменив нечаянно объект действия. Но это отдельный разговор, в вашем примере все прозрачно: "Я гляжу" - "у меня опускаются".

Answer (score 2):

Еще один возможный вариант:

***При виде того,** что происходит, у меня опускаются руки.*

Устойчивый оборот  "у меня опускаются руки" желательно сохранить, а без деепричастия можно обойтись.

Самый близкий вариант **с деепричастием:**  *Глядя на то, что происходит, можно **опустить** руки.*

Наличие **инфинитива** позволяет использовать деепричастный оборот, отнесенный к **безличному** предложению.

Розенталь: §212. Деепричастные обороты http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/69.htm

2. в безличном предложении при инфинитиве, например: Приходилось работать в трудных условиях, не имея в течение многих недель ни одного свободного дня для отдыха.

Comment: «Самый близкий вариант с **деепричастием:** _Глядя на то, что происходит, можно **опустить** руки_». Я не совсем согласна с такой трактовкой. Можно опустить руки — можно их и не опускать. Но ведь автор утверждает, что «у меня опускаются руки» (действие все-таки происходит).

Comment: Римма,   я свой первый варинт предлагаю в качестве  приемлемой редакцией. Вариант с деепричастием привожу только для того, что автор на примере своего текста видел, когда допустимо использование деепричастной конструкции.

Answer (score 2):

Простой вариант без лишних грамматических витьеватостей, аka деепричастий:

> Смотрю на то, что происходит, и у меня опускаются руки.

Answer (score 1):

У глагола-сказуемого и связанного с ним деепричастного оборота в русском языке *общий производитель действия*, поэтому вышло, что руки не только опускаются, но ещё и "поглядывают". Отсюда - два пути исправления: (1) убрать деепричастный оборот или (2) привести сказуемое в соответствие с имеющимся оборотом.

> (1) При взгляде на происходящее у меня опускаются руки.

> (2)  Глядя на то, что происходит, я теряю желание что-либо делать.